# Header Column of Gridview not aligning

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

The last header column of my gridview isnt aligning for some reason, im unsure why, any help?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStudents" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SQLGetStudents" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover">
    <alternatingrowstyle backcolor="#d0e6f4" forecolor="#545454"/>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PERSON_CODE" HeaderText="Student ID" 
            SortExpression="PERSON_CODE" >
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="STUDENTNAME" HeaderText="Student Name" 
            SortExpression="STUDENTNAME" >
        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger" />
        <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" >Add</asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);"  />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAdd" runat="server" Checked="True" onclick = "Check_Click(this)"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The particular part of my gridview that doesnt seem to be working is here:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" >Add</asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);"  />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAdd" runat="server" Checked="True" onclick = "Check_Click(this)"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />

        </asp:TemplateField>
```

but i thought id add all of the gridview just in case i messed up elsewhere

The Column shows up like this:
[image: The column shows up like this:]

Comment: Aligning to what? All the headers are displayed in the center of the column.

Comment: Thats the point, they're not.. The checkbox isnt aligning to the centre and i dont know why

Comment: They do when I tried your snippet. What happens when you remove `CssClass="table table-striped table-hover"` from the GridView?

Comment: same problem still, i'm so confused right now